# Listview doesn't refresh data with notifydatasetchanged with Asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am adding items to an ArrayList in the background of an AsyncTask. On the PostExecute I create a custom adapter where I pass in the ArrayList. 
When I want to add more items the ListView does not refresh. So far I have:

```
private class ProgressBlogList extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    ProgressBar blog_progress;
    ProgressBar laProgress = new ProgressBar(getActivity(), null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);
    ArrayList<Integer> posts = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        blog_lista = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.blog_list);
        blog_progress = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.blog_progress);
        if (blog_lista.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            blog_lista.addFooterView(laProgress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        arraydir = db.getTenItemBlogList(arraydir, id_number);
        for(int i = 0; i<arraydir.size(); i++){
            Integer post = arraydir.get(i).getId_post();
            posts.add(post);
        }
        arrayImages = db.getImagePost(posts);
        id_number = arraydir.size();

        db.close();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
        AdapterBlogList adapter = new AdapterBlogList(getActivity(), arraydir,arrayImages);
        blog_lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        index = blog_lista.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = blog_lista.getChildAt(0);
        top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
        blog_lista.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        blog_lista.removeFooterView(laProgress);
        blog_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(e.getMessage(), "Error IVAN::");
        }
        blog_lista.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
        blog_lista.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) {
                    if (footerProgress != null) {
                        if (footerProgress.getStatus() != Status.RUNNING) {
                            footerProgress = new ProgressBlogList();
                            footerProgress.execute();
                        }
                        }else{
                        footerProgress = new ProgressBlogList();
                        footerProgress.execute();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        blog_lista.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);

    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend you separate the Activity where you manage your ListView from the AsyncTask. Each part has its purpose, don't mix. I would pass the result ArrayList to the Activity where you would manage your ListView, and obtain it through an Intent, and after create the Adapter, it's more cleaner and probably will fix your problem

Comment: i think notifydatasetchange() work when you update the same adapter object you pass to the list but here you are creating new adapter object each time. So notifydatasetchanged() doesn't make sense.

Comment: thanks for the answers, but I tried to not recreate the adapter, doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: Hi please post an answer explaining how you solved this and accept it. I am facing the same issue